# python high order function: generic functions calls with parameter list

Tags: python, functional-programming, callable

I am looking for a high order function in python that takes in a function as parameter and a list of corresponding parameters, and call the function on the parameter list. Something like:

```
def exec(func,paramlist):
    return CALL(func,paramlist)
```

The paramlist length is undetermined, since it goes with each func passed in. The CALL should be able to extract the elements in the list and put each parameter in the right slot and make the function call.

For reference, in [Q language](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/DotSymbol) there is this "apply" function that handles generic function calls:

```
f1: {x}
f2: {x+y}
execFunction: {[fun;param] .[fun;param] }
execFunction[f1;enlist 1] // result is 1
execFunction[f2;(1 2)] // result is 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `func` expects multiple parameters and `paramlist` is a list of parameters, is as simple as this:

```
func(*paramlist)
```

Answer (score 2):

Python used to have an `apply` function but it was removed in Python 3 because it is so easy to unpack a list into individual arguments using the * operator. In fact an `apply` function can be written like so:

```
def apply(func, paramlist)
    return func(*paramlist)
```

This is so trivial, of course, that you wouldn't bother to write a function for it; you'd just write `func(*paramlist)` wherever you needed it.